# Link CSS files in a static file and use it for all folders even sub folders

Tags: css

I want to ask if there is a way to link css files in a static file and link the static file for all folders even sub folders with out change the path (../ or ../../) of these css files that is in the static file when link the static file in sub folders.

Comment: I honestly don’t know what you’re asking, but it *seems* that you want to use one css file for all your pages and use the same url to link to that file? If so, then use either absolute, or root-relative, url. If that’s not what you’re asking then you need to find someone, a friend or colleague, to help you better translate your question into English in order that we can better help you.

Comment: yeah how can i use the root folder to link css files ?